# MySQL get the latest products with distinct product_name from a particular month

Tags: mysql

I've the following `product` table in my database. I want to get the rows of all the products with distinct `product_name` added in the month of Dec in the descending order of their `id`.

```
id  product_name    qty month
1   Apple           20  Dec
2   Banana          40  Jan
3   Cherry          60  Jun
4   Apple           25  Dec
5   Banana          50  Dec
6   Papaya          20  Dec
7   Guava           34  Aug
8   Watermelon      55  Mar
9   Apple           75  Dec
10  Orange          32  Dec
```

The resulting table should be as below:

```
id  product_name    qty month
10  Orange          32  Dec
9   Apple           75  Dec
6   Papaya          20  Dec
5   Banana          50  Dec
```

So far I've come up with the following query and it doesn't get the result I need.

```
SELECT * 
FROM product 
WHERE month = "Dec" 
GROUP BY product_name 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

The problem with this query is that it gets the first row/record of Apple rather than last one as shown in table below:

```
id  product_name    qty month
10  Orange          32  Dec
6   Papaya          20  Dec
5   Banana          50  Dec
1   Apple           20  Dec
```

Can anyone help me write a proper mysql query for this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data as well formatted text. As it is right now it's really very difficult to follow what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Please fix your formatting.

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos, Tim Biegeleisen: I've formatted my question to the best of my skill. You can now run the snippet to see tables. Its so sorry that stackoverflow doesn't allow <table> tags in questions.

Comment: @razn  Your question is very unclear. Please specify what you your question. If you need help formulating the SQL statement, show what statement you wrote and your database structure.

If you need help to get the dynamic data into an html, say what templating / what language you want to use.

You are getting downvoted because you don't actually provide a question that can be answered, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can just use the `{}` symbol on the editor to format table data. This way it is easier for us to read and consume the data to create a mock-up of your use-case.

Comment: @RolandStuder I want to get all rows of the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT MAX(id), product_name  
FROM product 
WHERE month = "Dec" 
GROUP BY product_name
```

to get the biggest `id` per `product_name`:

**Output:**

```
max_id  product_name
9       Apple
5       Banana
10      Orange
6       Papaya
```

Using the above query as a derived table you can join back to the original table in order to get the rest of the fields:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM product AS t1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id, product_name  
   FROM product 
   WHERE month = "Dec" 
   GROUP BY product_name
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.max_id and t1.product_name = t2.product_name
ORDER BY t1.id
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/ZZM86515)

Comment: Appreciate ur effort so much, Giorgos. Your solution made my day.